# Problems with property access of selected value

Tags: knockout.js

Unfortunately I have problems to get my bindings working correctly.

Here is my ViewModel which is initialized with a list of JSON objects:

```
function ViewModel() {
    this.chains = ko.observableArray();
    this.selectedChain = ko.observable();
}
var model = new ViewModel();

$.ajax({
    url: "/GetAll/Chains",
    success: function (result) {
        model.chains(result);
        ko.applyBindings(model);
    }
});
```

The binding in my view looks like this:

```
<select data-bind = "
    options: chains, 
    optionsText: function(item) { return item.BusinessModel['Name'] }, 
    value: selectedChain"></select>
```

Till here everything is working properly. But now I have problems with the access of the properties of `selectedChain` on a different element. (For example name or id).

```
<input data-bind = "text: selectedChain.Id" /> // not working
```

What is the reason that I cannot access the properties? In the debugger I can see that the objects in list on initializing is like exptected, but the selected value lost the data!?

Thanks for every help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **selectedChain** object is an observable. As such, to get the content of the observable, for example the "Id" property, you have to add "()", like this:

```
<input data-bind = "text: selectedChain().Id" />
```